# Error in with fetch call "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" and "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch

I'm doing a fetch in react and getting these errors and I cannot figure out how to fix it.  I am using TypeScript and a C# rest service.  It works fine in postman but having these issues in the client.

I have tried disabling all browser extensions and tried other browsers also. This did not work.
I'm expecting to receive a status "201" back from the REST Call.

on button click
`<Button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type='submit'onClick={e => {e.preventDefault() handleForm()}}>Register</Button>`

javascript:
`    async function handleForm() {
console.log(JSON.stringify({ ...registration }))

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:44309/api/Users/Register';

const data = {
    email: registration.email,
    userName: registration.username,
    password: registration.password,
    confirmPassword: registration.passwordConfirmation,
    userTypeId: 4
};

// Default options are marked with *
const response = await fetch(endpoint, 
{ 
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
  referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
});
return response.json(); 
}`
```

here is the C# rest method:
`    [HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult Register([FromBody] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{
var userExists = _dbContext.AppUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == applicationUser.Email);
//todo: add validation code

```
if (userExists != null)
{
    return BadRequest("User with the same email address already exists");
}

applicationUser.Password = HashService.HashPassword(applicationUser.Password);
#if (!DEBUG)
    applicationUser.ConfirmPassword = "True";
#endif

_dbContext.AppUsers.Add(applicationUser);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a few issues with this error that I found.

1. was a CORS issue, so I added CORS to my C# code.
2. My API was using HTTPS and the react client was running under HTTP.  I needed to configure the create-react-app to run over HTTPS instead of HTTP once I got that configured it worked great. I had a difficult time getting the HTTPS to work on Windows on the client until I found [this post](https://medium.com/@praveenmobdev/localhost-as-https-with-reactjs-app-on-windows-a1270d7fbd1f)